# Distributing a Python module with ffmpeg dependency

Tags: python, ffmpeg, distutils, software-distribution

Rookie software developer here. I’m working on a Python module that harnesses some functionality from the FFmpeg framework - specifically, the ebur128 filter function. Ideally the module will stand on its own as an independent, platform agnostic tool for verifying that audio clips comply with EBU loudness standards. It’s being designed so that end users need only perform one simple, (hopefully!) painless installation procedure, which will encompass the installation of both the FFmpeg libraries and my Python wrapper/GUI.

I apologize for the rather vague question, but does anyone have general advice for creating Python module with external dependencies, or specific advice for standardizing the FFmpeg installation across platforms? [Distutils](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/) seems pretty helpful – are there other guidelines or standard practices for developing a neatly packaged Python tool? I want to minimize any installation headaches for end users.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For Windows

I think it will be easy to find ffmpeg binaries that work on any system, just like for Qt or whatever GUI library you are using. You can ship these binaries with your project and things will work (you may want to distinguish 32 bit and 64 bit systems, though).

It looks like you want to create a software that is self-contained and easily installable for end-users. Inkscape is such an example -- its installer contains Python and all other dependencies, in binary form (if required). That is, for Windows, you do **not** need to create a real Python package (which would allow installation with pip), and you do **not** need to look into distutils (which supports building C extensions). Both you do not need/want, I guess.

Maybe it will be enough for you to assemble a good directory structure and to distribute a ZIP archive with your software. This is enough if you do not need to interact with the Windows registry, for instance. Such programs are usually called "standalone", in the Windows world. However, you might still want to have a real Windows installer (even if it is just a self-extracting archive). The following article covers your requirements, I believe: http://cyrille.rossant.net/create-a-standalone-windows-installer-for-your-python-application/
It suggests using http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php for creating such an installer.

### Other platforms

On other operating systems it will be more difficult. For instance, I think it will be almost impossible to create ffmpeg binaries that run on every Linux system, because ffmpeg itself has so many binary dependencies. I do not know whether you can statically build ffmpeg at all.

Comment: Thanks so much Jan-Philip: this was most helpful, and I very much appreciate your addressing this on a platform-specific basis.

Comment: Just to follow up on this: I successfully used PyInstaller to bundle my python script and all its dependencies into a clean installer for Windows. I'm finding the Mac counterpart more difficult, however. I can get the GUI to launch from the executable, but when I try to initiate an ffmpeg process (using a wxpython thread), no matter how I structure my directory hierarchy I keep getting the following:  File "/.../out00-PYZ.pyz/threading", line 530, in __bootstrap_inner" ... File "/.../out00-PYZ.pyz/subprocess", line 1202, in _execute_child OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.